# HTML using label to select checkbox and bring to top of page

Tags: html, forms, checkbox, label

I have a page that has a checkbox at the top.   I want a  down the page to select the checkbox so the user can continue.
The problem is when you click the label, it scrolls to the checkbox directly at the top of the users screen.  However I need the page to go to the top of the page as well so the user can see everything above the check box.

Sample:
Top of page ID = #top
...

```
<input class="css-checkbox" id="PSRchk" type="radio" name="PSR" value="YES" required>
<label class="css-label" for="PSRchk">YES</label>                 
<input class="css-checkbox" id="PSRchk2" type="radio" name="PSR" value="NO" onclick="location.href='#PSR'">
<label class="css-label" for="PSRchk2">NO</label>

    ... Pages of code ...


    <label for="PSRchk">I Agree</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you may need to re-think your page layout.

You can use a anchor tag instead and set its href to #top like

```
<a href="#top">I Agree</a>
```

This will then go to the top of the page or wherever the `<div id="top"></div>` resides.

Comment: Right.  But I want the I agree link to auto check the check box and go to the top at the same time

Comment: Then you would need to add some javascript to your page. Have been able to create a fiddle showing this intended functionality? It will make it easier to collaborate. http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I figured it out with Javasctipt:

```
<a onclick="return iagree()">I Agree</a>

    <script>
    function iagree() {
        $('html,body').scrollTop(0);
        document.getElementById("PSRchk").checked = true;
    }
    </script>
```